# What book is "HP" in Shadowrun?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

[The **Chummer** character creator](http://www.chummergen.com/) has a reference to "HP". What book is this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In RPGGeek's listing of Shadowrun 4th edition supplements the only book that has the initials "HP" is [*Hazard Pay*](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/123244/hazard-pay), so that's almost certainly it.